# React App Fails to Compile Due to eslintrc File in a Distant Parent Directory

Tags: reactjs, package.json, eslintrc

I have a react app I have tried to upgrade from 16 to 17. It uses eslint. I have an eslintrc file in the project directory. The eslintrc file is in the same directory as the package.json file. The same directory I'm trying to run `npm run start`.

However, I get an error...

```
Failed to load config "airbnb" to extend from.
Referenced from: /Users/name/Sites/work/site-name/web/core/.eslintrc.json
```

My React app is in...

```
/Users/name/Sites/work/site-name/web/modules/custom/module_name/react/
```

So I can't figure out why it cares about an eslintrc file miles away in a parent directory.

This is a Drupal site, but honestly, I'm just trying to run the app out of its own directory right now. So Drupal shouldn't be getting involved. Plus I've had this setup working well for over a year now. Only after upgrading is it being problematic.

### Details:

- create-react-app v4.0.3
- Node v10.24.0
- NPM 6.14.11 (tried v7 too)

### Directory Structure

```
| build
| node_modules
| public
| src
|-- components
|-- index.js
| .eslintrc
| package.json
```

### Package.json File

```
{
  "name": "product-configurator",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "concurrently": "4.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.23.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.15.0",
    "eslint-config-wesbos": "^1.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^6.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.23.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "^17.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "react-ga": "^3.3.0",
    "react-inner-image-zoom": "^2.0.1",
    "react-socks": "2.0.2",
    "react-transition-group": "^2.2.1",
    "react-typist": "^2.0.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "build": "react-scripts build && for i in ./build/static/*/*; do cp $i `echo $i | sed -E \"s/\\.[0-9a-z]{8}\\./\\.drupal\\./g\"`; done",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "lint:fix": "eslint . --fix"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

### .eslintrc File

```
{
  "extends": [
    "wesbos"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never could get this worked out exactly. I ended up moving my eslint config to package.json.

```
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "wesbos"
    ]
  },
```

Not entirely sure what the issue was with .eslintrc file. But at least I have it working.